# research in module theory

Tags: reference-request, modules

I am interested in module theory mainly in connection with commutative algebra. I would like to know what are the main areas of research in this field and who are the researchers more active in it. I am asking this question because I want to do research in the area.

To improve the question, for example I would like to know what are the relevant papers about prime submodules.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted without explanation.  I think your question is very well-intended, but perhaps it's a little too broad?  Maybe you could give an example of what made you interested in module theory as it pertains to commutative algebra?  Also, I think (and I could be wrong) there is a "reference request" tag that you could put on this question to indicate that you are looking for additional information on the topic.

Comment: @ThyArtisMath: Thank you for your comment! I tried to make the question more precise and less broad.

Comment: Googling "Prime Submodules" gives already many papers. Have a look at the references there in each paper. Soon you will have a good idea about what is going on.

Comment: @spohreis:  You are very welcome.  I know how difficult it can be finding where to begin when you first start looking into topic, but in my experience it is simply a process of constantly narrowing down my search until I have something fairly specific to work with.  You'll get there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend searching through the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/%20%22arxiv) for any papers relating to prime module theory. Most mathematicians who work with modules use them for their research in Algebraic Geometry, Homological Algebra, Commutative Algebra, Representation Theory and almost any other Algebra heavy field.